# Solve Warning: no rule to process file for architecture x86_64

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

How can I solve this error when I am compiling an Cordova App in Xcode?

```
warning: no rule to process file '/DemoApp/platforms/ios/DemoApp/Plugins/onesignal-cordova-plugin/OneSignalPush.h' of type sourcecode.c.h for architecture x86_64
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Problem solved!
In Xcode, remove all .h (header) files from here: **Build Phases –> Compile Sources**.

Comment: You should also remove all `.json` files